# Uncaught TypeError in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, undefined, meteor

I have this code:

```
Meteor.subscribe('practices');

Session.set('practice', 'Practice 1');

Template.laps_t.laps = function () {
  var obj = Practices.findOne({name: Session.get('practice')});
  return obj.lap_n;
};
```

And I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lap_n' of undefined`.

I know that `lap_n` is in fact a property of `obj`.

I'm not using autosubscribe. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

SOLVED. Thanks guys.

if(obj){ return obj.lap_n } like you said did the trick.

Comment: `lap_n` is not a property of `obj` if you are getting that error, since `obj` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always check for existence of objects inside templates. The way this works is that the Template will be immediately executed upon pageload, possibly even before the subscription has retrieved the mongo data from the server, so in that case your `obj` will be undefined and will not have the property you expect. But since Templates are reactive, once the data is available, your `Practices.findOne` call will be re-evaluated and the template re-executed. And then it will work.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I understand. But in that case, how do I access my `lap_n` from inside the template? I have to reverse `lap_n` before I send it to the template, that's the real problem..

Comment: Like @crapthings said, just use `if (obj)` to check first whether the object exists, and then you can access whatever property you want.

Comment: Doing that, it will return false and the template does nothing. I already tried it;

Comment: `if (obj) { return obj.lap_n; } else { return "0"; }` should work, right?

Comment: My problem is that I need to reverse lap_n (which is a list).
Is there a reverse {{#each }} or something similar?

Comment: Just `return obj.lap_n.reverse()`?

Answer (score 0):

you might have to wait until data arrive, so may be you can try to add

```
if obj
    return obj.lap_n
else
    return {
        lap_n: 0
    }
```

Comment: Doing that, it will return false and the template does nothing. I already tried it;

Comment: With that code you don't wait for nothing. It just evaluates the conditionals and assigns 0 to lap_0 everytime.

Comment: My problem is that I need to reverse lap_n (which is a list).
Is there a reverse {{#each }} or something similar?